# Question about "Quotient Group of Cyclic Group is Cyclic"

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I found a [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Group_of_Cyclic_Group) of the fact that

> if $G$ is a cyclic group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ is a cyclic subgroup.

They don't mention that $H$ is a normal subgroup. But to define the quotient group, doesn't $H$ have to be normal?

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Group_of_Cyclic_Group

Comment: Yes, but a cyclic group is always commutative, so each subgroup of it is always normal.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that detail.

Comment: This is not a detail, but some important insight for a beginner in abstract algebra. It is the start to understand, what a normal subgroup really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyclic groups are abelian. Let $h\in H$, $g\in G$ for $H\le G$, abelian $G$. Then $$ghg^{-1}=gg^{-1}h=h\in H.$$ Thus $H\unlhd G$.